# Showing the existence of cycle of not a multiple of 3 in the below Graph satisfying the other conditions

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose $G(V,E)$ is a simple graph with $deg(v) = 3$ $\forall v \in$ V . Show that $G$ has a cycle of length $\not\equiv$ $0 (mod3)$.

- My progress :

> I tried using the fact that as its having degree greater than 1 for all vertices there must be a cycle . I also tried bounding on how mamy cycles minimum and maximum it can have for small cases but didnt get any idea which helps in solving the generalization ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $k$ be the diameter (maximum path length) of $G$

Choose a path $x_0,...,x_k$ of length $k$.

Since $\deg(x_0)=3$, there are two vertices adjacent to $x_0$ other than $x_1$.

By maximality of $k$, it follows that $x_0$ is adjacent to each of $x_i,x_j$ for some $i,j$ with $1 < i < j\le k$.

Then we get the cycles

- $x_0,...,x_i,x_0$ of length $i+1$.$\\[4pt]$

  $x_0,...,x_j,x_0$ of length $j+1$.$\\[4pt]$

  $x_0,x_i,...,x_j,x_0$ of length $j-i+2$.

but $i+1,j+1,j-i+2$ can't all be divisible by $3$.